# Intrepolating between two data frames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, interpolation

i have two data frames

a=

```
x   y
10  10
47  9
58  8
68  7
75  6
80  5
```

b=

```
x   y
45  10
55  9
66  8
69  7
79  6
82  5
```

I want to interpolate between them and generate new data frame with N sampling rate

assume N=3 for this example

output is

```
x          y
10          10
17.5    10
45          10
47           9
51           9
55           9
68           7
68.5        7
69           7
75          6
77          6
79          6
80          5
81          5
82          5
```

what funcions of pandas should I use ?? please help !

Answer (score 0):

First, you could use [df.sample](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html) to generate new datas for x only after [pd.merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) data. Then you should use [df.interpolate](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.interpolate.html#pandas.DataFrame.interpolate) ... You've got some example on [my gist](https://gist.github.com/gyassine/b47b90e8de935cc06ef856401f7582b0) for interpolation...

```
dataset = pd.merge(a, b, left_on ='x', right_on='x', how='outer')
dataset = dataset.interpolate(method='slinear')
```